# CreateObject("AcroExch.App") gives No such interface supported error

Tags: vba, acrobat

Using VBA in Excel I have the following:-

```
Dim Aapp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim toDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim fromdoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
        
Set Aapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set toDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set fromdoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
```

I have Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library installed and ticked under VBS Tools->References and the autofill works when I type Acrobat. etc finding CAcroAPP. However when I set through the code I get the following on the `Set Aapp = CreatObject("AcroExch.App")` line.

> Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)': No such interface supported.

Anyone know what causes this and how to fix it please.

Comment: Have you got Acrobat installed?

Comment: Yes. Tools->References includes Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. From what I have read that is all that needs installing or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have an acrobat licence to create PDFs?